# How to correctly install solaris on Google Colab

Tags: pip, conda, google-colaboratory

During the past few weeks, I have been trying to install [solaris](https://github.com/CosmiQ/solaris) on google colab but with no success. I tried all the following approaches and none of them has worked:

- Creating a conda environment as recommended by the authors in https://github.com/CosmiQ/solaris

- Directly through **pip**

- Cloning the repository and access the folders and functions directly

- Using **mamba** as suggested here [How to install solaris (on colab or locally)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73334818/how-to-install-solaris-on-colab-or-locally)

All of these approaches failed so far. Basically, there is a wheel building error for **GDAL**. Which is already installed on Colab. I do not find any proper documentation or other failure descriptions.

I highly appreciate every hint. Thanks a lot

**Edit:** Here is a full stack trace of every cell I ran on google colab following @merv 's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73334818/how-to-install-solaris-on-colab-or-locally) :

**1) Installing mamba:**

```
!pip install -q condacolab
import condacolab
condacolab.install()
```

> ⏬ Downloading
> https://github.com/jaimergp/miniforge/releases/latest/download/Mambaforge-colab-Linux-x86_64.sh...
>  Installing...  Adjusting configuration...  Patching
> environment... ⏲ Done in 0:00:38  Restarting kernel...

**2) Enabling the GPU on colab manually and creating the solaris environment:**

```
!wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CosmiQ/solaris/main/environment-gpu.yml
!mamba env update -n base -f environment-gpu.yml
```

> --2022-10-14 11:03:28--  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CosmiQ/solaris/main/environment-gpu.yml
> Resolving raw.githubusercontent.com (raw.githubusercontent.com)...
> 185.199.108.133, 185.199.109.133, 185.199.110.133, ... Connecting to raw.githubusercontent.com
> (raw.githubusercontent.com)|185.199.108.133|:443... connected. HTTP
> request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK Length: 734 [text/plain]
> Saving to: ‘environment-gpu.yml’
>
> environment-gpu.yml 100%[===================>]     734  --.-KB/s    in
> 0s
>
> 2022-10-14 11:03:29 (41.6 MB/s) - ‘environment-gpu.yml’ saved
> [734/734]
>
> [+] 0.0s pytorch/linux-64  ⣾  pytorch/noarch
> 8.0kB @  99.5kB/s  0.1s [+] 0.1s pytorch/linux-64      ⣾   conda-forge/linux-64  ⣾   conda-forge/noarch    ⣾   pkgs/main/linux-64
> ⣾   pkgs/r/noarch         ⣾  pytorch/linux-64
> [+] 0.2s conda-forge/linux-64  ⣾   conda-forge/noarch    ⣾
> pkgs/main/linux-64    ⣾   pkgs/r/linux-64       ⣾   pkgs/r/noarch
> ⣾  [+] 0.3s conda-forge/linux-64  ⣾   conda-forge/noarch    ⣾
> pkgs/main/linux-64    ⣾   pkgs/r/linux-64       ⣾   pkgs/r/noarch
> ⣾  [+] 0.4s conda-forge/linux-64  ⣾   conda-forge/noarch    ⣾
> pkgs/main/linux-64    ⣾   pkgs/r/linux-64       ⣾   pkgs/r/noarch
> ⣾  pkgs/r/noarch                                      pkgs/r/linux-64
> [+] 0.5s conda-forge/linux-64  ⣾   conda-forge/noarch    ⣾
> pkgs/main/linux-64    ⣾   pkgs/main/noarch      ⣾  [+] 0.6s
> conda-forge/linux-64  ⣾   conda-forge/noarch    ⣾   pkgs/main/linux-64
> ⣾   pkgs/main/noarch      ⣾  pkgs/main/noarch
> [+] 0.7s conda-forge/linux-64  ⣾   conda-forge/noarch    ⣾
> pkgs/main/linux-64    ⣾  [+] 0.8s conda-forge/linux-64  ⣾
> conda-forge/noarch    ⣾   pkgs/main/linux-64    ⣾  [+] 0.9s
> conda-forge/linux-64  ⣾   conda-forge/noarch    ⣾   pkgs/main/linux-64
> ⣾  [+] 1.0s conda-forge/linux-64  ⣾   conda-forge/noarch    ⣾
> pkgs/main/linux-64   100%pkgs/main/linux-64
> [+] 1.1s conda-forge/linux-64  ⣾   conda-forge/noarch    ⣾  [+] 1.2s
> conda-forge/linux-64  ⣾   conda-forge/noarch    ⣾  [+] 1.3s
> conda-forge/linux-64  ⣾   conda-forge/noarch    ⣾  [+] 1.4s
> conda-forge/linux-64  ⣾   conda-forge/noarch    ⣾  [+] 1.5s
> conda-forge/linux-64  ⣾   conda-forge/noarch    ⣾  [+] 1.6s
> conda-forge/linux-64  ⣾   conda-forge/noarch    ⣾  [+] 1.7s
> conda-forge/linux-64  ⣾   conda-forge/noarch    ⣾  [+] 1.8s
> conda-forge/linux-64  ⣾   conda-forge/noarch    ⣾  [+] 1.9s
> conda-forge/linux-64  ⣾   conda-forge/noarch    ⣾  [+] 2.0s
> conda-forge/linux-64  ⣾   conda-forge/noarch    ⣾  [+] 2.1s
> conda-forge/linux-64  ⣾   conda-forge/noarch   100%[+] 2.2s
> conda-forge/linux-64  ⣾  conda-forge/noarch
> [+] 2.3s conda-forge/linux-64  ⣾  [+] 2.4s conda-forge/linux-64  ⣾
> [+] 2.5s conda-forge/linux-64  ⣾  [+] 2.6s conda-forge/linux-64  ⣾
> [+] 2.7s conda-forge/linux-64  ⣾  [+] 2.8s conda-forge/linux-64  ⣾
> [+] 2.9s conda-forge/linux-64  ⣾  [+] 3.0s conda-forge/linux-64  ⣾
> [+] 3.1s conda-forge/linux-64  ⣾  [+] 3.2s conda-forge/linux-64  ⣾
> [+] 3.3s conda-forge/linux-64  ⣾  [+] 3.4s conda-forge/linux-64  ⣾
> [+] 3.5s conda-forge/linux-64  ⣾  [+] 3.6s conda-forge/linux-64  ⣾
> [+] 3.7s conda-forge/linux-64  ⣾  [+] 3.8s conda-forge/linux-64  ⣾
> [+] 3.9s conda-forge/linux-64  ⣾  [+] 4.0s conda-forge/linux-64  ⣾
> [+] 4.1s conda-forge/linux-64  ⣾  [+] 4.2s conda-forge/linux-64  ⣾
> [+] 4.3s conda-forge/linux-64  ⣾  [+] 4.4s conda-forge/linux-64  ⣾
> [+] 4.5s conda-forge/linux-64  ⣾  [+] 4.6s conda-forge/linux-64  ⣾
> [+] 4.7s conda-forge/linux-64  ⣾  [+] 4.8s conda-forge/linux-64  ⣾
> [+] 4.9s conda-forge/linux-64  ⣾  [+] 5.0s conda-forge/linux-64  ⣾
> [+] 5.1s conda-forge/linux-64  ⣾  [+] 5.2s conda-forge/linux-64  ⣾
> [+] 5.3s conda-forge/linux-64  ⣾  [+] 5.4s conda-forge/linux-64
> 100%[+] 5.5s conda-forge/linux-64 100%[+] 5.6s conda-forge/linux-64
> 100%[+] 5.7s conda-forge/linux-64 100%[+] 5.8s conda-forge/linux-64
>
> Looking for: ["python[version='>=3.6']", "pip[version='>=19.0.3']",
> "affine[version='>=2.3.0']", 'albumentations=0.4.3',
> "fiona[version='>=1.7.13']", 'gdal=3.0.3',
> "geopandas[version='>=0.7.0']", "matplotlib[version='>=3.1.2']",
> "networkx[version='>=2.4']", "opencv[version='>=4.1']",
> "pandas[version='>=0.25.3']", "pyproj[version='>=2.1']",
> "pytorch[version='>=1.3.1']", 'pyyaml=5.2',
> "rasterio[version='>=1.0.23']", 'requests=2.22.0',
> "rtree[version='>=0.9.3']", "scikit-image[version='>=0.16.2']",
> "scipy[version='>=1.3.2']", "torchvision[version='>=0.5.0']",
> 'cudatoolkit=9.2', "tqdm[version='>=4.40.0']",
> "urllib3[version='>=1.25.7']", 'tensorflow-gpu=1.13.1', 'cuda100',
> 'shapely']
>
> Pinned packages:
>
> - python 3.7.*
> - python_abi 3.7.* *cp37*
> - cudatoolkit 11.2.*
>
> Encountered problems while solving:
>
> - conflicting requests

3. **Then, here I manually restarted the runtime as suggested by @merv and carried on installing solaris:**

   `!pip install solaris`

> Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple,
> https://us-python.pkg.dev/colab-wheels/public/simple/ Collecting
> solaris   Downloading solaris-0.4.0-py3-none-any.whl (17.8 MB)
> ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 17.8/17.8 MB 74.2 MB/s eta 0:00:00 Collecting requests==2.22.0   Downloading
> requests-2.22.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (57 kB)
> ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 58.0/58.0 kB 8.3 MB/s eta 0:00:00 Collecting rasterio>=1.0.23   Downloading
> rasterio-1.2.10-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (19.3 MB)
> ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 19.3/19.3 MB 75.7 MB/s eta 0:00:00 Collecting numpy>=1.17.3   Downloading
> numpy-1.21.6-cp37-cp37m-manylinux_2_12_x86_64.manylinux2010_x86_64.whl
> (15.7 MB)
> ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 15.7/15.7 MB 87.4 MB/s eta 0:00:00 Requirement already satisfied: tqdm>=4.40.0 in
> /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from solaris) (4.64.0)
> Collecting pyproj>=2.1   Downloading
> pyproj-3.2.1-cp37-cp37m-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (6.3 MB)
> ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 6.3/6.3 MB 106.1 MB/s eta 0:00:00 Requirement already satisfied: pip>=19.0.3 in
> /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from solaris) (22.2.2)
> Collecting scipy>=1.3.2   Downloading
> scipy-1.7.3-cp37-cp37m-manylinux_2_12_x86_64.manylinux2010_x86_64.whl
> (38.1 MB)
> ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 38.1/38.1 MB 16.3 MB/s eta 0:00:00 Collecting pyyaml==5.2   Downloading PyYAML-5.2.tar.gz
> (265 kB)
> ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 265.7/265.7 kB 27.8 MB/s eta 0:00:00   Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done Collecting
> gdal>=3.0.2geopandas>=0.7.0   Downloading GDAL-3.5.2.tar.gz (756 kB)
> ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 756.8/756.8 kB 52.9 MB/s eta 0:00:00   Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done Collecting
> fiona>=1.7.13   Downloading
> Fiona-1.8.21-cp37-cp37m-manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (16.7 MB)
> ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 16.7/16.7 MB 82.5 MB/s eta 0:00:00 Collecting scikit-image>=0.16.2   Downloading
> scikit_image-0.19.3-cp37-cp37m-manylinux_2_12_x86_64.manylinux2010_x86_64.whl
> (13.5 MB)
> ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 13.5/13.5 MB 101.8 MB/s eta 0:00:00 Collecting networkx>=2.4   Downloading
> networkx-2.6.3-py3-none-any.whl (1.9 MB)
> ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 1.9/1.9 MB 77.9 MB/s eta 0:00:00 Collecting opencv-python>=4.1   Downloading
> opencv_python-4.6.0.66-cp36-abi3-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl
> (60.9 MB)
> ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 60.9/60.9 MB 16.1 MB/s eta 0:00:00 Collecting affine>=2.3.0   Downloading
> affine-2.3.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (16 kB) Collecting shapely>=1.7.1dev
> Downloading
> shapely-2.0a1-cp37-cp37m-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl
> (2.2 MB)
> ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 2.2/2.2 MB 91.1 MB/s eta 0:00:00 Collecting albumentations==0.4.3   Downloading
> albumentations-0.4.3.tar.gz (3.2 MB)
> ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 3.2/3.2 MB 99.9 MB/s eta 0:00:00   Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done Requirement already
> satisfied: urllib3>=1.25.7 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages
> (from solaris) (1.26.11) Collecting torch>=1.3.1   Downloading
> torch-1.12.1-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (776.3 MB)
> ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 776.3/776.3 MB 2.1 MB/s eta 0:00:00 Collecting matplotlib>=3.1.2   Downloading
> matplotlib-3.5.3-cp37-cp37m-manylinux_2_5_x86_64.manylinux1_x86_64.whl
> (11.2 MB)
> ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 11.2/11.2 MB 94.7 MB/s eta 0:00:00 Collecting rtree>=0.9.3   Downloading
> Rtree-1.0.1-cp37-cp37m-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl
> (1.0 MB)
> ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 1.0/1.0 MB 68.8 MB/s eta 0:00:00 Collecting pandas>=0.25.3   Downloading
> pandas-1.3.5-cp37-cp37m-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl
> (11.3 MB)
> ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 11.3/11.3 MB 109.8 MB/s eta 0:00:00 Collecting torchvision>=0.5.0   Downloading
> torchvision-0.13.1-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (19.1 MB)
> ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 19.1/19.1 MB 78.6 MB/s eta 0:00:00 Collecting tensorflow==1.13.1   Downloading
> tensorflow-1.13.1-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (92.6 MB)
> ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 92.6/92.6 MB 11.4 MB/s eta 0:00:00 Collecting imgaug<0.2.7,>=0.2.5   Downloading
> imgaug-0.2.6.tar.gz (631 kB)
> ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 631.4/631.4 kB 52.0 MB/s eta 0:00:00   Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done Collecting
> opencv-python-headless>=4.1.1   Downloading
> opencv_python_headless-4.6.0.66-cp36-abi3-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl
> (48.3 MB)
> ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 48.3/48.3 MB 18.3 MB/s eta 0:00:00 Collecting urllib3>=1.25.7   Downloading
> urllib3-1.25.11-py2.py3-none-any.whl (127 kB)
> ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 128.0/128.0 kB 17.1 MB/s eta 0:00:00 Collecting chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2   Downloading
> chardet-3.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (133 kB)
> ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 133.4/133.4 kB 17.4 MB/s eta 0:00:00 Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in
> /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from
> requests==2.22.0->solaris) (2022.6.15) Collecting idna<2.9,>=2.5
> Downloading idna-2.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (58 kB)
> ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 58.6/58.6 kB 7.9 MB/s eta 0:00:00 Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.10.0 in
> /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from
> tensorflow==1.13.1->solaris) (1.16.0) Collecting
> tensorflow-estimator<1.14.0rc0,>=1.13.0   Downloading
> tensorflow_estimator-1.13.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (367 kB)
> ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 367.6/367.6 kB 36.4 MB/s eta 0:00:00 Collecting protobuf>=3.6.1   Downloading
> protobuf-4.21.7-cp37-abi3-manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (408 kB)
> ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 408.4/408.4 kB 41.0 MB/s eta 0:00:00 Collecting absl-py>=0.1.6   Downloading
> absl_py-1.3.0-py3-none-any.whl (124 kB)
> ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 124.6/124.6 kB 16.3 MB/s eta 0:00:00 Collecting termcolor>=1.1.0   Downloading
> termcolor-2.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (5.4 kB) Collecting
> tensorboard<1.14.0,>=1.13.0   Downloading
> tensorboard-1.13.1-py3-none-any.whl (3.2 MB)
> ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 3.2/3.2 MB 95.1 MB/s eta 0:00:00 Collecting keras-preprocessing>=1.0.5   Downloading
> Keras_Preprocessing-1.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (42 kB)
> ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 42.6/42.6 kB 5.0 MB/s eta 0:00:00 Collecting grpcio>=1.8.6   Downloading
> grpcio-1.49.1-cp37-cp37m-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl
> (4.7 MB)
> ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 4.7/4.7 MB 29.0 MB/s eta 0:00:00 Collecting gast>=0.2.0   Downloading
> gast-0.5.3-py3-none-any.whl (19 kB) Requirement already satisfied:
> wheel>=0.26 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from
> tensorflow==1.13.1->solaris) (0.37.1) Collecting astor>=0.6.0
> Downloading astor-0.8.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (27 kB) Collecting
> keras-applications>=1.0.6   Downloading
> Keras_Applications-1.0.8-py3-none-any.whl (50 kB)
> ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 50.7/50.7 kB 6.0 MB/s eta 0:00:00 Collecting munch   Downloading
> munch-2.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (10 kB) Collecting cligj>=0.5
> Downloading cligj-0.7.2-py3-none-any.whl (7.1 kB) Collecting attrs>=17
> Downloading attrs-22.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (58 kB)
> ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 58.8/58.8 kB 8.2 MB/s eta 0:00:00 Collecting click-plugins>=1.0   Downloading
> click_plugins-1.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (7.5 kB) Requirement already
> satisfied: setuptools in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from
> fiona>=1.7.13->solaris) (65.3.0) Collecting click>=4.0   Downloading
> click-8.1.3-py3-none-any.whl (96 kB)
> ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 96.6/96.6 kB 11.5 MB/s eta 0:00:00 Collecting python-dateutil>=2.7   Downloading
> python_dateutil-2.8.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (247 kB)
> ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 247.7/247.7 kB 30.7 MB/s eta 0:00:00 Collecting pillow>=6.2.0   Downloading
> Pillow-9.2.0-cp37-cp37m-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl
> (3.1 MB)
> ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 3.1/3.1 MB 99.8 MB/s eta 0:00:00 Collecting kiwisolver>=1.0.1   Downloading
> kiwisolver-1.4.4-cp37-cp37m-manylinux_2_5_x86_64.manylinux1_x86_64.whl
> (1.1 MB)
> ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 1.1/1.1 MB 53.6 MB/s eta 0:00:00 Collecting packaging>=20.0   Downloading
> packaging-21.3-py3-none-any.whl (40 kB)
> ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 40.8/40.8 kB 5.3 MB/s eta 0:00:00 Collecting pyparsing>=2.2.1   Downloading
> pyparsing-3.0.9-py3-none-any.whl (98 kB)
> ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 98.3/98.3 kB 15.5 MB/s eta 0:00:00 Collecting fonttools>=4.22.0   Downloading
> fonttools-4.37.4-py3-none-any.whl (960 kB)
> ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 960.8/960.8 kB 69.0 MB/s eta 0:00:00 Collecting cycler>=0.10   Downloading
> cycler-0.11.0-py3-none-any.whl (6.4 kB) Collecting pytz>=2017.3
> Downloading pytz-2022.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (500 kB)
> ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 500.8/500.8 kB 41.4 MB/s eta 0:00:00 Collecting snuggs>=1.4.1   Downloading
> snuggs-1.4.7-py3-none-any.whl (5.4 kB) Collecting
> typing-extensions>=3.7   Downloading
> typing_extensions-4.4.0-py3-none-any.whl (26 kB) Collecting
> tifffile>=2019.7.26   Downloading tifffile-2021.11.2-py3-none-any.whl
> (178 kB)
> ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 178.9/178.9 kB 24.4 MB/s eta 0:00:00 Collecting PyWavelets>=1.1.1   Downloading
> PyWavelets-1.3.0-cp37-cp37m-manylinux_2_5_x86_64.manylinux1_x86_64.manylinux_2_12_x86_64.manylinux2010_x86_64.whl
> (6.4 MB)
> ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 6.4/6.4 MB 108.2 MB/s eta 0:00:00 Collecting imageio>=2.4.1   Downloading
> imageio-2.22.1-py3-none-any.whl (3.4 MB)
> ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 3.4/3.4 MB 98.8 MB/s eta 0:00:00 Collecting importlib-metadata   Downloading
> importlib_metadata-5.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (21 kB) Collecting h5py
> Downloading
> h5py-3.7.0-cp37-cp37m-manylinux_2_12_x86_64.manylinux2010_x86_64.whl
> (4.1 MB)
> ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 4.1/4.1 MB 100.7 MB/s eta 0:00:00 Collecting werkzeug>=0.11.15   Downloading
> Werkzeug-2.2.2-py3-none-any.whl (232 kB)
> ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 232.7/232.7 kB 29.7 MB/s eta 0:00:00 Collecting markdown>=2.6.8   Downloading
> Markdown-3.4.1-py3-none-any.whl (93 kB)
> ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 93.3/93.3 kB 14.1 MB/s eta 0:00:00 Collecting mock>=2.0.0   Downloading
> mock-4.0.3-py3-none-any.whl (28 kB) Collecting zipp>=0.5   Downloading
> zipp-3.9.0-py3-none-any.whl (5.8 kB) Collecting MarkupSafe>=2.1.1
> Downloading
> MarkupSafe-2.1.1-cp37-cp37m-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl
> (25 kB) Building wheels for collected packages: albumentations,
> pyyaml, gdal, imgaug   Building wheel for albumentations (setup.py)
> ... done   Created wheel for albumentations:
> filename=albumentations-0.4.3-py3-none-any.whl size=60767
> sha256=7bcb141f9585fbb0beb8a33aab783ac32b3cd5f16f0435ab5b0c385266f0281b
> Stored in directory:
> /root/.cache/pip/wheels/9d/f4/ab/b45b873b6399eeb93386bee4f8bddb9ad0e2f54d34cde20861
> Building wheel for pyyaml (setup.py) ... done   Created wheel for
> pyyaml: filename=PyYAML-5.2-cp37-cp37m-linux_x86_64.whl size=392175
> sha256=0c488989cbef4a01e9afee81f73902e8377654ea57292befe4b9fc92751d5b74
> Stored in directory:
> /root/.cache/pip/wheels/c5/67/65/80b02387630c3794fc9bab68ca0de3dd87d639d65936026527
> error: subprocess-exited-with-error
> × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.   │ exit code: 1   ╰─> See above for output.
> note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.   Building wheel for gdal (setup.py) ... error
> ERROR: Failed building wheel for gdal   Running setup.py clean for
> gdal   Building wheel for imgaug (setup.py) ... done   Created wheel
> for imgaug: filename=imgaug-0.2.6-py3-none-any.whl size=654004
> sha256=e57c2d822e81dd9be607f0e10d275e8b6cf6255ac0e45d2e8100bbdd49f8db80
> Stored in directory:
> /root/.cache/pip/wheels/89/72/98/3ebfdba1069a9a8eaaa7ae7265cfd67d63ef0197aaee2e5f9c
> Successfully built albumentations pyyaml imgaug Failed to build gdal
> Installing collected packages: pytz, chardet, affine, zipp, urllib3,
> typing-extensions, termcolor, pyyaml, python-dateutil, pyproj,
> pyparsing, protobuf, pillow, numpy, networkx, munch, mock, MarkupSafe,
> idna, grpcio, gdal, gast, fonttools, cycler, attrs, astor, absl-py,
> werkzeug, torch, tifffile, tensorflow-estimator, snuggs, shapely,
> scipy, rtree, requests, PyWavelets, pandas, packaging,
> opencv-python-headless, opencv-python, kiwisolver,
> keras-preprocessing, importlib-metadata, imageio, h5py, torchvision,
> scikit-image, matplotlib, markdown, keras-applications, click,
> tensorboard, imgaug, cligj, click-plugins, tensorflow, rasterio,
> fiona, albumentations, solaris   Attempting uninstall: urllib3
> Found existing installation: urllib3 1.26.11
> Uninstalling urllib3-1.26.11:
> Successfully uninstalled urllib3-1.26.11   Attempting uninstall: idna
> Found existing installation: idna 3.3
> Uninstalling idna-3.3:
> Successfully uninstalled idna-3.3   error: subprocess-exited-with-error
> **>      × Running setup.py install for gdal did not run successfully.   │ exit code: 1   ╰─> See above for output.
> note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.   Running setup.py install for gdal ... error
> error: legacy-install-failure**

**> × Encountered error while trying to install package. ╰─> gdal**

> note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
> hint: See above for output from the failure.

**4) Importing solaris:**

```
import solaris
```

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in 
> ----> 1 import solaris
>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'solaris'
>
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- NOTE: If your import is failing due to a missing package, you can
> manually install dependencies using either !pip or !apt.
>
> ### To view examples of installing some common dependencies, click the
> "Open Examples" button below.

So, we can clearly see that **solaris** has not been installed successfully due to an error during the installation of the module **gdal**.

Comment: How does [the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73334818/how-to-install-solaris-on-colab-or-locally) fail? Please add details to question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi @merv, thanks a lot for reading my question and commenting here. I have edited my question and I provided the full stack trace of every cell code  I ran on google colab following your the answer you've provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73334818/how-to-install-solaris-on-colab-or-locally). Please check it out, thanks a lot.

Comment: Preliminarily, the YAML looks incompatible with Colab because Colab now has `cudatoolkit=11.2` installed. The YAML will definitely have to be edited, and likely in multiple places. Consider raising an Issue on the repository (though the project doesn't appear actively maintained).